# how to apply same rule to several properties in validation.yml symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, yaml

Using Symfony2.3.4, Doctrine2 and PHP5.6.3.

My `validation.yml`:

```
Project\NameBundle\Entity\EntityName:
    properties:
        f1:
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*$/"
                message: "mismatch"

        f2:
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*$/"
                message: "mismatch"
```

What I need could be something like:

```
Project\NameBundle\Entity\EntityName:
    properties:
        [f1, f2]:
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*$/"
                message: "mismatch"
```

This throws error of course, I just hope something similar exists to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Why is first (working) solution not feasible ?

Comment: @Miro; size of the file maybe, less coding, you name it, and this is just for 2 fields, what for more?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about size of the file and less coding, that is premature optimization (which is root of all evil, apparently :). BUT, if you REALLY need more complicated validation on multiple fields, you need to create custom validator on class level, like describe here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator